# $p_1p_2...p_n +1$ is not square for $p_k = k$'th prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

how to prove $\forall n$  : $p_1p_2...p_n +1$ isn't the perfect square. $p_i$ is $i$th prime number.

Comment: More generally, if $d$ is odd, then $2d+1$ cannot be a perfect square.

Comment: To elaborate on that, you should know that a number of the form $4k+3$ is never a perfect square.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $n \ge 1$. Since $2$ is the first prime, our product is even. Thus $p_1\cdots p_n+1$ is odd. Suppose it is equal to the odd perfect square $m^2$.

Note that $m^2-1$ is divisible by $4$, indeed by $8$. But $p_1\cdots p_n$ is not divisible by $4$. Thus $p_1\cdots p_n+1$ cannot be a perfect square.

**Remark:** The prime $2$ played a crucial role in this argument. Note for example that $3\cdot 5+1=4^2$, and $11\cdot 13 +1=12^2$.

Comment: if $4|m^2-1$ then ${p_1}^2...{p_n}^2+2p_1...p_n\equiv 0 \pmod 4$. since $p_1$ is $2$ so ${p_1}^2=4$ and $2p_1=4$

Comment: It is best not to square. Suppose that $p_1\cdots p_n=m^2-1$. TThe since $4$ divides $m^2-1$, we get that $4$ divides $p_1\cdots p_n$. But this is false.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P_n = \underbrace{\color{red}{p_1}p_2 \cdots p_n}_{Q_n} +1$. As $\color{red}{p_1}=2$ and $2 \nmid p_i$ for $i≥2$ therefore $Q_n \equiv  2$(mod $4$) $\implies P_n \equiv 3$(mod $4$). But for $n \in \mathbb{Z}, n^2 \not \equiv  3$(mod $4$). Therefore $P_n$ is not a perfect square. $\Box$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$(1)\;\;\;\;\;\forall\,n\in\Bbb Z\;\;,\;\;\;n^2=0,1\pmod 4$$

$$(2)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{What Thomas Andrews wrote in his comment above}$$

Comment: first hint is wrong because: $2d+1=4k+3$ and ${4k+3}^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ but ${4k+3}^2 \equiv 9 \pmod {10}$ and by theorem we know just $0,1,4,5,6,9$ can be for perfect square.

Comment: @agustin, I'm afraid you're missing something important. I wrote $$\forall\,n\in\Bbb Z\;\;,\;\;n^2=0,1\pmod 4\,$$ This is not only true but rather very easy to prove.