# Let P denote the product of first n prime numbers (with n > 2). Find all values of $n$ .

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, problem-solving, square-numbers

> Let P denote the product of first n prime numbers (with $n > 2$). For what values of n we
> have. 
> $1.$ $P - 1$ is a perfect square. 
> $2.$ $P + 1$ is a perfect square.

**What I Tried**: I have almost solved Part $2$, and I have some ideas of Part $1$. 
For Part $2$, let $P + 1 = k^2$ . 
$\rightarrow P = (k + 1)(k - 1) . $

So, after experimenting with some values of $n$, I observed that $P + 1$ is a perfect square when $n = 2,4$ . 
When it is $3*5$ it works, and in the next $n$ it works as we get $3 * 5 * 7 * 11 = 33 * 35$ . 
I was not able to get any other $n$, and if there is a proof, I need help to get it.

For Part $1$, I didn't know how to do it algebraically, so I experimented with some $n$. Obviously $P - 1$ won't be prime for $n = 2,4$. However, I noticed that Part $1$ does not work for any $n$, but I was not able to get a proof for it.

Can someone help me with these two parts? Thank You.

**Edit**:- I just now noticed that I thought myself that $n$ meant the starting prime value, which is wrong. It meant that $n$ is the total no. of starting primes, so my approach for Part $2$ was wrong.

Comment: "but I was not able to get a proof for it" - it is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323978/a-problem-in-prime-number-and-perfect-square).

Comment: Thank you, that solves half of my problem already.

Comment: Yes, this has been solved. See also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) for more references. The sequence of primorials starts with $(2, 6, 30, 210, 2310, \cdots)$.

Comment: Nothing in the problem specifies that $2$ should be left off the list.  Did you intend to make that assumption?

Comment: But $n>2$ does not mean $p>2$, careful

Comment: You also confusingly use $n$ in two roles here: a) as the number of primes multiplied to get $P$; b) the number that is $\sqrt{P\pm1}$

Comment: @Anonymous  $n$ is the number of primes, not the primes themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints :**

For $n>2$,

- $(P-1)$ is $2$ modulo $3$.
- $(P+1)$ is $3$ modulo $4$.

Comment: Thanks, I have got it already. That means for both the parts, for no $n$ can$ (P \pm 1)$ is a perfect square.

Comment: @Anonymous Correct for $n \ge 2$ only :)